# Is a relational database needed?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am in the middle of attempting to help my company digitize their history. One project is taking maintenance records for equipment and putting them into a mysql database. The idea is to be able to pull up a history at any time without flipping through piles and piles of paper.

My experience is limited to using phpMyAdmin to create tables and fumbling through php to output data how I want it. I've never used a relational setup.

The data fields would always be the same, the database would be populated via copy/paste from Excel (until such time comma delimited importing can be figured out), and this data would not need to be edited by endusers. It is strictly for viewing/printing purposes only.

Example fields:
id, unit number, unit_type, date, maintenance_performed

My question is, would putting all this into one table be an acceptable way to accomplish this task? Or would a relational setup be better due to the different types of units? Why?

Comment: You will want to read about [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and [foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). Possibly [relational algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) if you like going hardcore.

Comment: Why use a database at all? Sounds like a job for a spreadsheet. However if you do need a database, then yes by all means include those relations.

Comment: What you are trying to do can be done in a spreadsheet or Microsoft Access for that matter, at a fraction of the cost and effort. If you are going to use a database, try to put a little bit of architecture in it. Like you will need 2 tables, Projects, and Maintenance and Maintenance references Projects.

Comment: The reason for a database is so that it can be easily accessed from the web by anybody in the company (field technicians) no matter where they are. I had considered a Google Doc spreadsheet, but it may get unruly and difficult to read (we have 10,000+ documents, adding several hundred per week).

Answer (score 2):

I would focus on getting the data into the database and not on its storage. You are going to have enough problems copy-and-pasting the data in. For instance, how will you ensure that the dates are always in a consistent format?

After the data is loaded into tables, then you can worry about how to optimize it for querying purposes. How will new records continue to be uploaded? That will be a very important part of the process (I would recommend having field a creation date in the database, in addition to other information in the record).

After the data is loaded, you can worry about the best structure for organizing it. This is analogous to a real archivist, who tends to start by gathering lots and lots of data, and then figuring out the best way to organize it.